# Mikrotik Scripting: Get Interface IP

Tags: mikrotik, router-os

I want to get the `local-address` property of a `pppoe-client` interface, which is my public internet IP.

Assuming that the name of the interface is `my-pppoe-out`, what is the proper `interface pppoe-client get` command to use?

I couldn't find anything useful in the [official wiki](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/PPPoE) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the IP directly on the command-line, you must use a script to do this.

```
:local ip [/ip address get [find interface="pppoe-out1"] address ];
:put "IP: $ip"
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the variable $ip  (here i just write it in the console) like updating a dyndns, etc.

To use this script, either copypaste it in a file like "ip.rsc" and then type "import ip.rsc" to execute it, or put it on a routerOS script (/system script add ..).

Comment: For any future visitors, you may also want to remove the `/24` subnet mask at the end of the IP. For doing so, I found this answer: http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=97732

Comment: Not sure why you believe this command cannot be executed in command-line. Note that `:local` variables are not cached, so either use `{ }` around your snippet or use `:global` variables - then it works.